# Angularjs ng-model in input does not update value in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, angularjs-ng-model

Can anyone explain to me why when I print `console.log($scope.inputvalue)` the variable is not updated with the values that I enter in the `input`?

Maybe I just misunderstood the meaning of `ng-model`, in this case, how do I pass a value from the view to controller?

```js
(function () {
'use strict';

angular.module('LunchCheck', [])
.controller('checkiftoomuch', ['$scope', checkiftoomuch]);

function checkiftoomuch($scope){
    $scope.inputvalue = "";
    console.log($scope.inputvalue);
}

})();
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="LunchCheck">
  <head>
    <title>Lunch Checker</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style>
      .message { font-size: 1.3em; font-weight: bold; }
    </style>
  </head>
<body>
   <div class="container" ng-controller="checkiftoomuch">
     <h1>Lunch Checker</h1>

         <div class="form-group">
             <input id="lunch-menu"
             type="text"
             placeholder="list comma separated dishes you usually have for lunch"
             class="form-control"
             ng-model="inputvalue">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
             <button class="btn btn-default">Check If Too Much</button>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group message">
           Total number of disches: {{ inputvalue }}
         </div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: “Whenever you have ng-model there’s gotta be a dot in there somewhere. If you don’t have a dot, you’re doing it wrong.” . Your problem is that the inputValue you are editing is inside a subdirective scope, not your controller's. You have to put your input in an object like `$scope.state = { inputValue : 0 }` and use `ng-model="state.inputValue"`

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant - I would beg to differ here, one can always use a variable directly attached to the scope, without making it an object property. The `inputValue` is definitely in the controller's scope.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava no you can't. The best approach is to use the controllerAs: you use `'controllerAs': '$ctrl'` in your directive declaration, and use `this.inputValue` in the controller instead of `$scope.inputValue`, and in the view use `ng-model="$ctrl.inputValue"` . It won't be in $scope, just attached to the `this` of the controller.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Have you run the code snippet provided above? The view is updated without the use of any object or a `controllerAs` syntax.

Comment: didn't read your code, seems you had another problem. But anyway, your `ngmodel="inputvalue"` WILL become a problem if you use directives around the input (ng-if etc...) since there will be a new scope, in that case $scope.inputvalue from your controller will not return the displayed value.

Comment: Agreed that you would need an object based approach if using directives. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `$scope.inputvalue = "";` before the `console.log`. But after you change the value, you need to `console.log` it again. 
Try using:

```
function checkiftoomuch($scope){
    $scope.inputvalue = "";
    console.log($scope.inputvalue);

    $scope.$watch('inputvalue', function(newValue, oldValue){
        console.log(newValue);
    })
}
```

Or add a function on your button click like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showValue()>Check If Too Much</button>
</div>
```

And in JS:

```
function checkiftoomuch($scope){
    $scope.inputvalue = "";
    console.log($scope.inputvalue);

    $scope.showValue = function(){
        console.log($scope.inputvalue);
    }
}
```

AngularJS has 2-way data binding which means, the values in the view and controller are in sync always, they do not have to be passed back and forth.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still struggling understanding the sync concept between view and controller. I thought the variable in the controller would be automatically updated after the changes in view. So, I guess I didn't properly understand the function of ng-model.

Comment: The variable is indeed updated in the controller, which you also see in your view with the `{{ inputValue }}`. It was just a matter of getting the value into the console _after_ the value had changed.